# Is it bad design using static variables for core parts instances?

Tags: java, static-variables

Developing a jogl application, this is (a part of) our core class structure

main jFrame

- viewer (for rendering)

  - inputListener
  - viewpole (for camera/projection control)
  - graph (holds nodes/meshes)

    - icon handler (to expand/collapse a node with children)

So if I want to call methodX() in the icon handler(that is basically the texture representing the handler, it is the same for all the nodes), I have to call:

```
Main.instance.getViewer().getGraph().getIconHandler().methodX()
```

where instance is a static variable holding the instance of the main jFrame

Given they are all:

1) instantiated once

2) at the begin

3) are supposed to be there for the whole time

4) in theory, no problem of race conditions, we are using `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock` at lower level when we add/read/modify/delete nodes

is it dangerous/bad design assigning the instance of each class to a static variable inside each corresponding class?

so that if I want to access the same `methodX()` I would just call

```
IconHandler().instance.methodX()
```

Ps: I read some of the other questions regarding static variables() but I found them quite generic, mine regards the core parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you know that you'll only ever need one instance of each class, this is okay. This is called a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and is a pretty well-known design pattern.

The problem is that you probably **can't** guarantee that you only need one instance of your classes. Singletons are good for things like data connections or file readers, where there is a built-in limit to the number of instances that should access the data.

You're misusing the static keyword as a lazy way to gain access to an instance of a class, and it's going to come back and bite you when you expand your program to include multiple instances of those classes. And if you think you'll only ever need one instance- you can't guarantee that will never change.

Comment: Btw, it still didnt bite me back! :p

Comment: @elect It's only been a few months. Wait until you get into this habit over multiple projects, and then have all the software you've written for 10 years not be able to support a new feature request.